# Deschifer this bit of code please

Tags: php, codeigniter, meta-tags

What does the following bit of code mean in "English"?

Just started learning PHP & Codeigniter and cant seem to make sense of it.

```
<meta name="description" content="<?if (isset($contentdata) && isset($contentdata->description)):?><?=$data->description?><?=$contentdata->description?><?endif;?>" />
```

As far as i understand, it gets info from the database, but i'm not too sure how, or why the two conditions must be true (&&).

Comment: The code shown doesn't get the data from anywhere. It is template logic which basically says "if this data is loaded, display it". The data has already been loaded somewhere else, and passed to this template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//if there's a variable $contentdata AND it has a property ->description
<?if (isset($contentdata) && isset($contentdata->description)):?>

//shorthand syntax for <?php echo $data->description ?>
<?=$data->description?>

//shorthand syntax for <?php echo $contentdata->description ?>
<?=$contentdata->description?>
```